# What is the meaning of ':Q=' in variable name in batch cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following batch command line:

```
if not x%COMPUTERNAME%==x%COMPUTERNAME:Q=% (
    echo 1
) else (
    echo 2
)
```

What is the meaning of `:Q=` in the variable `COMPUTERNAME`
Whatever I enter as value of the variable it always goes to the else block.

Comment: this checks if the variable `%COMPUTERNAME%` contains a Q, for more information, look [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: `%variable:<searchstring>=<replacestring>%` replaces one string (in your example `Q`) with another (in your example an empty string)

Comment: Hi @Stephan, Dennis. Than you for your answers.
Please post an answer to be able to mark it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%variable:<searchstring>=<replacestring>%` replaces one string (in your example `Q`) with another (in your example an empty string)

The whole `if` is : *"if the variable is the same as when I remove the `Q` then"* or in other words: "*is there a `Q` in the variable?"*

Read the help for `set /?` and `if /?`